# @Transactional in spring JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a spring boot application where I need to update a migratedCustomer db table based on userId and phoneNumber.
Since I have to use for loop in the service layer for every update, it is creating a
new transaction and performance is hampered.
how could I make sure only one transaction is created and hence to improve the performance. code is like below

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MigratedCustomer")
public class MigratedCustomer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String userId;
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdTimestamp;
    private int batchNumber;
    private String comment;
}
```

```java
public class MigratedCustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void updateMsisdn(List<MigratedCustomer> savedCustomers) {
        for (MigratedCustomer savedCustomer : savedCustomers) {
            userRepository.updateStatus(savedCustomer.getUserId(), 
            savedCustomer.getPhoneNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public interface MsisdnRepository extends JpaRepository<Msisdn, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Msisdn SET status=INACTIVE where userId=:userId and phoneNumber=:phoneNumber",
           nativeQuery = true)
    void updateStatus(@Param("userId") String userId, @Param("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Make your service `@Transactional`.

Comment: thanks, do I have to use "@EnableTransactionManagement" for "@transactional" to work??

Comment: Spring Boot does that for you. If you want even more performance gain enable batching of statements in JPA.

Comment: it would be a favour if you could provide some link for JPA batching. thanks in advance

Comment: When it comes to JPA, [the blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) of Vlad is always helpful.